# Pandas array from url - only NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, download

I'm encountering a little problem when trying to download data from an url and putting it into an array using pandas:

When I simply do the following:

`EUR_USD_TICK = pd.read_csv('https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz')`

I get this error:

`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 14, saw 3`

Which I assume is due to the fact that the data retrieved from the url is compressed.

So I tried to set the compression to gzip:

`EUR_USD_TICK = pd.read_csv('https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz',compression='gzip')`

When doing that, I get no error message, however, the array is only composed by NaN values:

```
          D  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0       NaN         NaN         NaN
1       NaN         NaN         NaN
2       NaN         NaN         NaN
3       NaN         NaN         NaN
4       NaN         NaN         NaN
```

The length of the array matches the length of the csv file, so I have no idea why the array is filed with NaN values.

Would anyone have an idea of why I'm getting this issue?

Thanks

Ps: The csv data that I'm trying to download:

```
DateTime,Bid,Ask
01/04/2015 22:00:00.389,1.19548,1.19557
01/04/2015 22:00:00.406,1.19544,1.19556
01/04/2015 22:00:00.542,1.19539,1.19556
01/04/2015 22:00:00.566,1.19544,1.19556
```

Comment: well i dont think you have to worry about compression because when i try and download https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv it returns a file, but i can't find an encoding that works on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are some characters in the file that Python/pandas doesn't like ('\x00').

So I used the gzip module to manually read the file and then removed those characters. After that, Pandas reads the file without issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO,BytesIO
import gzip

r = requests.get('https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz')

gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(r.content))

pd.read_csv(StringIO(gzip_file.read().decode('utf-8').replace('\x00','')))
```